# Creating a java Clock. increasing time

Tags: java

I am creating a clock in Java. I have managed to do some very basic stuff and now i want to implement a function.

If i set the time to i.e. 12:04:59 and use my timeTick Method it will increase the time with 1 second but the problem is it will say the time is 12:04:60 and it doesn't change to 12:05:00.
I've been struggling a while now and i can't really find a solution to it.

My code is below, i hope you can help me,

```
 public class Clock{

        public int seconds;
        public int minutes;
        public int hours;

        public Clock ( int InsertSeconds, int InsertMinutes, int InsertHours){    

            seconds = InsertSeconds;
            minutes = InsertMinutes;
            hours   = InsertHours;
        }

        public void timeTick(){

            seconds = seconds + 1;

        }
        public String toString(){

            return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds; 

        }


    }
```

I am not planning to use Imports because i am a beginner it would be great if we can keep it simple.

Comment: First try to explain to yourself in words _under what condition do you want it to act differently_, and _what steps need to happen to 'fix' the time_.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here lays in the **timeTick()** function. In a real clock example we have some extra rules for counting. Every time we count to 60 seconds, we add a minute. Every time we count to 60 minutes, we add an hour. So you have to implement these rules.

```
// lets make some simple code
public void timeTick(){
     seconds = seconds + 1; // you can also use seconds++; it means exactly the same thing

     if(seconds == 60){
         minutes++; // we reached a minute, we need to add a minute
         seconds = 0; // we restart our seconds counter
         if(minutes == 60){
             hours++; // we reached an hour, we need to add an hour
             minutes = 0; // we restart our minutes counter
             // and so on, if you want to use days (24 h a day) , months ( a bit more difficult ), ...
         }
     }
}
```

I hope this will help you, for a starter it might be a good idea to split the second part of code into a function, which deals with this situation. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could check for when you have 60 seconds, then reset seconds to zero, and increase minutes by 1. e.g.

```
if (the condition you want to check) {
    //increase the number of minutes.
    //reset number of seconds.
}
```

If you're entering seconds values of more than 60, you'll need to work out how many minutes that equals using division, and the remaining number of seconds using the *modulus* operator: `%` e.g.

```
seconds = 125;
minutes = seconds / 60; // 2 minutes
remaining_seconds = seconds % 60; // 5 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions. the only problem now is that the rule wont apply when i construct and object of the class Clock. So i also need the rule to apply when i construct the following time 10:10:61

Comment: @WinstonNolten if you use the method I told you to use in you previous question for invalid time values input, you will not get '10:10:61' because if a user enters 61, they will be asked to input the time values again.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public void timeTick () {
    seconds++;
    while (seconds >= 60) {
        minutes++;
        seconds-=60;
    }
    while (minutes >= 60) {
        hours++;
        minutes-=60;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i used this one. The only problem is that after i use my method for showing me the time, it prints a zero instead of 00 i.e. 10:10:59 + 1 seconds changes into 10:11:0. I tried some stuff but i can't get it fixed

Comment: This is what i got.    public String setProperTimeFormat(){
   
        if(seconds < 10) {
            return "0" + seconds;
        }
        else {
            return "" + seconds;
        }
    }

Sorry for not adding code properly. I don't know how to use the taggs

Comment: @WinstonNolten The method that I suggested returns you an integer. But your suggested method looks good to convert the int to a string. To make a bit more common useable, you could use `public static String format (int i) { String str = Integer.toString(i); while (str.length() < 2) str = "0" + str; return str; }`. In future: include code in \`<your code>\`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public void timeTick () {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds == 60)
    {  
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes == 60)
        {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @msrd0 will you help me understand when our code gets edited, i don't want people to get troubled unnecessarily.(I am new to SO) :)

Comment: Where's your problem? If you disagree with my edit you can roll it back

Comment: no dude i don't disagree, i was just curious to know that under what circumstances do you edit them?

Comment: I edit them when I think that I can fix something in the post that doesn't change the meaning, or improve the readability of the post (especially the code). You can view all edits in the users profile, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/users/3755692/msrd0?tab=activity&sort=revisions

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class Clock{

    public int seconds;
    public int minutes;
    public int hours;

    public Clock ( int InsertSeconds, int InsertMinutes, int InsertHours){    

        seconds = InsertSeconds;
        minutes = InsertMinutes;
        hours   = InsertHours;
    }

    public void timeTick(){

        seconds = seconds + 1;
        if(seconds==60){
          minutes++;
          seconds=0;
          if(minutes==60){
             hours++;
             minutes=0;
          }
        }
    }
    public String toString(){

        return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds; 

    }


}
```